# its is possible to open to different forms in one from using splinter in C#

Tags: c#

i have a treeview on click each number i want that a new from open but i want to open it in exiting form split then by using splinter.
is their any way to open new form in splinter container part  2 while splinter container part  1 contain  treeview like the main menu of the program.
i do not want to open new form in a separate window i want to open it in  splinter container part  2.

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name == "Node1")
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.Show(); // Want to show it in  splinter container part  2
            MessageBox.Show("Open 1");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to set [TopLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel(v=vs.110).aspx) to False before adding the Form to your desired container:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name == "Node1")
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.TopLevel = false; // won't work without this!  
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(f); // add your form to the desired container
        f.Show(); // now display the form
    }
}
```